# Algorithm to find curve with tangents at set distances along curve

Tags: python, algorithm, geometry, curve

I'm looking to write (or ideally find) an algorithm for calculating an approximate curve given:

- Start and End points
- Tangents at given distances along the curve
- Fixed overall length of curve

So something like starting point (x_0, y_0) ending point (x_n, y_n) and a list of distances and angles [(a_0, 0), (a_1, d_1) ... (a_n, d_n)] where a_i is the tangent to the curve at distance d_i (along the curve) from (x_0, y_0) and d_n is the overall distance along curve from (x_0, y_0) to (x_n, y_n).

As the input will be comng from real-world data there won't be a precise solution but some sort of iterative approximation would be suitable.

My main problem is that I don't know if a class of curves like this have a name so I can search for it, ideally there will already be an algorithm I can use. Most things I've found assume know positions of control points.

More information about the problem:
It is actually in three dimensions but the range in the z direction is a lot smaller than than in x and y so for simplicity I think can be ignored. But for completeness, the z value is known at the start point, end point, and at every known tangent point.

The whole curve also smoothly changes over time (but with overall length and distance along the curve of tangent measurements remaining the same) so the curve at the previous time-step could be used as the starting point for a iterative solution.

I mainly work in python so if there is a numpy/scipy implimentation that would be ideal.

Comment: I think this question fits badly here, but greatly at https://math.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Chaikin's algorithm for curves can probably approximate a curve where you know the tangent point and the angle. You will probably need to use the intersection of two successive tangents as control points. You might have to identify inflection points. It is an iterative method. It is unclear if the distances remain constant between each point, and between iterations.   https://www.cs.unc.edu/~dm/UNC/COMP258/LECTURES/Chaikins-Algorithm.pdf

Comment: You might want to look at cubic splines at wikipedia:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_Hermite_spline   With it, you can create functions x(t) and y(t), piecewise from one point to the next, with the gradient derived from your tangents that you have for each point. With x and y being functions in t, you can also scale the dx/dt and dy/dt, a property sometimes called 'speed'. Scaling this will make the curve findthe way rather tight or in wider arcs when going from one point to the next. You might have an iterative solver that adjusts the speed until the total length of the curve fits.

Comment: @Ripi2 I did think the same but there seemed to be more similar questions (Beizer curve algorithms etc.) here. Is there a sensible way of moving a question or cross-posting? (Quite new to SO).

Comment: @Blindleistung thanks - I hadn't vome across Hermite Splines before.

Comment: Most algorithms you find here require `x,y` coordinates. But you're asking about *Tangents at given distances along the curve*, that's why I consider it more a maths question. The closest I can think of is [Euler spiral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_spiral). See also [clothoid](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3289195/688039) and [clothoid](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3359006/688039)

Answer (score 0):

I can try to suggest an approach, but there are details you need to figure out how to do.

You are looking for a curve `C(s) = [C_1(s), C_2(s)]` such that `s` is its arc-length parameter, i.e. `length( C(s) ) = s`. You want your arc-length parameter `s` to go through the points `0, d_1, d_2, ..., d_n` and at each point the angle between the tangent line to the curve and the horizontal x-axis to be `a_0, a_1, a_2, ..., a_n`.

In each interval `[d_(i-1), d_i]` pick two points `u_i, v_i` so that `d_(i-1) < u_i < v_i < d_i`. Also, pick an angle `b_i`.

Set up the continuous curve

```
T(s, u_i, v_i, b_i) = [ T_1(s, u_i, v_i, b_i), T_2(s, u_i, v_i, b_i) ]
                    when s in [d_(i-1), d_i]
```

by applying the following formulas:

```
T_1(s) = cos( a_(i-1) + (b_i - a_(i-1)) * (s - d_(i-1))/(u_i - d_(i-1)) )
T_2(s) = sin( a_(i-1) + (b_i - a_(i-1)) * (s - d_(i-1))/(u_i - d_(i-1)) )
       when s in [d_(i-1), u_i]

T_1(s) = cos( b_i )
T_2(s) = sin( b_i )
       when s in [u_i, v_i]

T_1(s) = cos( b_i + (a_i - b_i) * (s - v_i)/(d_i - v_i)) )
T_2(s) = sin( b_i + (a_i - b_i) * (s - v_i)/(d_i - v_i)) )
       when s in [v_i, d_i]
```

Putting together all these pieces of curves, gives you the global curve

```
T(s, u, v, b) = [ T_1(s, u, v, b),  T_2(s, u, v, b) ]  for s in [d_0, d_n]
              where u = [u_1, u_2,..., u_n], 
                    v = [v_1, v_2,..., v_n],
                    b = [b_1, b_2,..., b_n]
```

Observe that by definition, for each `s`

```
norm( T(s, u, v, b) ) = sqrt( T_1(s, u, v, b)^2 + T_2(s, u, v, b)^2 ) = 1
    (because T is defined simply as cos and sin of the same argument)
```

This identity holds exactly when the integral curve

```
D(s, u, v, b) = integral_from(0)_to(s)  T(t, u, v, b) dt
```

is arc-length parametrized, i.e. `length( D(s, u, v, b) ) = s` for all `s`. The curve `D(s, u, v, b)` is continuously-differentiable, because `T(s)` is continuous.

Observe that you can define a map

```
[u, v, b] --> D(d_n, u, v, b)
```

and you have enough parameters `u = [u_1,...,u_n],  v = [v_1,...,v_n]` and `b = [b_1,...,b_n]` to try to adjust them so that

```
D(d_n, u, v, b) = P_n - P_0
```

where `P_0 = [x_0, y_0]` and `P_n = [x_n, y_n]`, which are given, are the starting point and the end point of your curve. For example, observe that in each sub-interval [u_i, v_i] the integral curve is

```
D(s) = D(u_i) + s*[cos(b_i), sin(b_i)]
```

so it is a straight line. And the curved (in fact circular) portions of `D(s)` in the interval `[d_(i-1), d_i]` are concentrated in `[d_(i-1), u_i] union [v_i, d_i]`. So the closer the points `u_i` get to `d_(i-1)` and `v_i` to `d_i`, the more straight `D(s)` looks for most of `s`. This allows you to deform and manipulate the curve `D(s)` so that it can reach the point `P_n - P_0`.

As a result, a curve that satisfies your conditions is

```
C(s) = P_0 + D(s, u, v, b)
```

One attempt to choose the parameters so that your curve, which starts from P_0, also ends up at P_n, could be the following:

try to minimize the function 
`E(u, v, b) = norm( D(d_n, u, v, b) + P_0 - P_n )^2` with respect to the parameters `[u, v, b]`. You can try to use gradient descent method in an attempt to reach parameters for which `E(u, v, b) = 0`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion - I think it will take a while to work through!

Comment: @Ben I know it will take time. I really wanted to help but the thing is that the conditions for your curve pose restrictions that are quite tough and it looks like the solution requires a lot of work.